# Отображение двух моделей на одной странице html

Tags: django, модули, views

недавно начал познавать django, но столкнулся с проблемой. Создал 2 модуля. Один модуль отображается на странице, а вот второй нет. Максимально искал в интернете, но к сожалению не смог найти.

Если более конкретно, то Акции отображаются, а вот Игры нет. В html после создания "таблицы" в админке изменений не появляется. Как будто блок: *{% for a in games %}* не работает.

Есть подозрения, что у меня проблема с views.py, но понять не могу, что сделать. Была идея попробовать *class IndexPageView(ListView):*

**index.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="stock_block">
        {% for sale in sales %}
            <a href="#" class="st_1" hx-post="{{ request.path }}?id={{ sale.id }}" hx-target=".modal-body">
                <div class="st_text1">{{ sale.title }}</div>
                <div class="st_text2" >Нажми, чтобы узнать подробнее</div>
                <div class="st_blur"></div>
                <img src="{{ sale.cover }}">

            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

           {% block game %}
        <div class="games_ramka">
           {% for a in games %}
            <div class="game_1">
                <div class="startblur">
                    <a href="#"><div class="startgame">
                        <div class="iconstart"></div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="blur_game"></div>
                <div class="name_game">{{ a.gtitle }}</div>
                <img src="{{ a.gcover }}">
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Akcii
from .models import GameStin


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.htmx:
        id = request.GET.get('id')
        context = {'sale': Akcii.objects.get(id=id)}
        return render(request, 'main/partials/htmx_show_popup.html', context=context)



    sales = Akcii.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'sales': sales})


def gami(request):
    games = GameStin.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'games': games})
```

**url.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('', views.gami)
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Роут path('', views.gami) у вас не работает т.к. путь такой уже есть. Параметр context у функции render - это те самые переменные, которые будут отображаться у вас на странице, исправьте на

```py
def index(request):
    games = GameStin.objects.all()
    if request.htmx:
        id = request.GET.get('id')
        context = {'sale': Akcii.objects.get(id=id), 'games': games}
        return render(request, 'main/partials/htmx_show_popup.html', context=context)



    sales = Akcii.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'sales': sales, 'games': games})
```

Comment: Всё заработало! Я был близок, но сам не смог разгадать данную загадку, спасибо вам^^